# Solving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^8+5}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^8+5}\  \mathrm{d}x?$$

It's very hard for me to solve above integral. Please help me.

Comment: Do you know about complex functions? I mean the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: NO , if you  have some information , i glad to read

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E8%2B5%29

Comment: there is no Step by Step for this integral !!!!! i can not solve it

Comment: There are complex methods to solve such improper integrals. For example by these methods we can obtain $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2m}}{x^{2n}+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{2n}\csc \big((2m+1)\pi/(2n)\big)$$.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the answer to 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^8 + 5}\,dx?
$$
Or, do we *need* to use the improper integral?  What are you computing this integral for (as in, which class, or what kind of application)?  Would a numerical approximation be sufficient?

Comment: No problem, whatever methods you can try, give us some hints or solution :)

Comment: @MohammadAlipour I meant to ask do we *need* to use the *indefinite* integral?  Also, what class or application is this for, and would a numerical approximation be sufficient?

Comment: See the chapter 7 Sec 79  of : http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~wei/teach/122/Brown-Churchill-Complex%20Variables%20and%20Application%208th%20edition.pdf

Comment: @MohammadAlipour Read the answer (using complex analysis) to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318983/how-to-solve-the-improper-integral-int-infty-infty-fracx2x69dx?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{x^n+a^n}~dx$ can be shown to equal $a^{k-n}~\dfrac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi n\bigg)$ using the following method: First, substitute $x=at,$ then let $u=\dfrac1{t^n+1},$ and recognize the expression of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral. Lastly, employ Euler's [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to establish the final result.

Answer (score 2):

If one knows the [Euler $\Gamma$ function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2),
$$
\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty u^{s-1} e^{-u}\:{\rm{d}}u, \quad s>0,
$$
and some of its properties then one may write
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^8+5} \:{\rm{d}}x
\\\\&=2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^8+5} \:{\rm{d}}x
\\\\&=2\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^{+\infty} x^2e^{-(x^8+5)t} \:{\rm{d}}t\right){\rm{d}}x
\\\\&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-5t}\left(\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^8 t}\:{\rm{d}}x\right)\:{\rm{d}}t
\\\\&=\frac14\int_0^\infty t^{-3/8}e^{-5t}\left(\int_0^\infty u^{3/8-1} e^{-u}{\rm{d}}u\right)\:{\rm{d}}t\quad (x=u^{-1/8}t^{-1/8})
\\\\&=\frac1{4\cdot5^{5/8}}\left(\int_0^\infty v^{-3/8}e^{-v}\:dv\right)\left(\int_0^\infty u^{3/8-1} e^{-u}{\rm{d}}u\right)\quad (v=5t)
\\\\&=\frac1{4\cdot5^{5/8}} \Gamma\left(1-\frac38\right)\Gamma\left(\frac38\right)
\\\\&=\frac{\pi}{4\cdot5^{5/8}\sin \frac{3\pi}8}
\\\\&=\frac{\pi}{2\cdot5^{5/8}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^8+5}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^8+5}\,dx = \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^{8/3}+5}{\phantom{deleted excess dz}} $$
by setting $x=z^{1/3}$ in the last step. Now, by setting $z=5^{3/8}w$,
$$ I = \frac{2}{3\cdot 5^{5/8}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dw}{w^{8/3}+1}, $$
but for any $\alpha > 1$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dw}{w^\alpha+1} = \frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)} $$
due to Euler's beta function and the $\Gamma$ reflection formula. It follows that:

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^8+5}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2^{5/4}\cdot 5^{5/8}\cdot\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}}. $$

Comment: (Do you want $-\infty$ as your lower limit in the first integral?)

Comment: @user84413: oh, sure, now fixing.